# Memory leak in constant memory of CUDA-capable GPUs?

Tags: memory-leaks, cuda, gpu

In CUDA C progamming guide it is noted:

> *global* function parameters are passed to the device:
>   via constant memory and are limited to 4 KB on devices of compute capability 2.x and higher.

Considering that the constant memory has a lifetime of an application, in a case that a kernel is called thousands of times within an application, I'd like to know if the function parameters are freed automatically after each time the kernel is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant memory has a lifetime of an application, but it can be changed (asynchronously) from host code.  Since there is a cache involved, there may be nuances around cache invalidation, but that is not germane to your question, I don't think.

Yes, the constant memory used for kernel call parameters is freed at the end of the kernel call, and can be reused for subsequent kernel calls,